# spring entity update query check result

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I have entity class accountant. 
I am trying save updated values of it.
I am unable to do it.

I dont see any error logs . How do I check if the update query executed successfully or not

```
@Repository("accountantRepository")
@Transactional
public interface AccountantRepository extends JpaRepository<Accountant, Long> {

     public final static String UPDATE_ACCOUNTANT = "update Accountant acct SET acct.password =:password, acct.phoneNumber =:phoneNumber,"
            + " acct.state =:state, acct.postCode =:postCode, acct.country =:country where acct.id =:accountantId ";

@Query(UPDATE_ACCOUNTANT)
 @Modifying
 void updateAccountant(@Param("password") String password, @Param("phoneNumber") String phoneNumber,
         @Param("state") String state, @Param("postCode") String postCode, @Param("country") String country,
         @Param("accountantId") String accountantId);
}
```

In my accountantServiceImpl.java class I do

```
public void updateAccountant(Accountant acct) {

    accountantRepository.updateAccountant(acct.getPassword(), acct.getPhoneNumber(), acct.getState(),
            acct.getPostCode(), acct.getCountry(), acct.getId());       
}
```

Comment: Why so complicated. Remove your `updateAccountant` method and just call `AccountantRepository.save`. You are basically trying to work around JPA with this.

Comment: I am trying to edit a existing record. When I do 'save', it creates a new record in db. Thats y using custom update query. I want to check y my update query is not updating

Comment: Then what you are doing is still a hack. Which means you are working around JPA. A save should be all you need Hibernate is smart enough to Figure out if it needs to update or not.

Answer (score 0):

hibernet save() will update only when **primary key** (most of the cases it is "id" field) **is set in the object which you passing to save()** method. If it does not find, it tries to insert a new record, which will succeed incase you don't have any DB level constraints.

JPD also provides to have your own custom implementation. You can do this.

1. Create an interface **AccountantRepositoryCustom** and add the method you want e.g. **updateAccountant**.

   `public interface AccountantRepositoryCustom {
    void updateAccountant();
    }`
2. Extend your repository with this customer interface

`public interface AccountantRepository extends JpaRepository<Accountant,  Long> , AccountantRepositoryCustom`

3. Create an implementation class **AccountantRepositoryImpl** for AccountantRepositoryCustom

`public class AccountantRepositoryImpl implements AccountantRepositoryCustom { 
 @Override
 public void updateAccountant () {
  // you code here 
 }`

NOTE : The name of custom interface and implementation class are importantant as JPA follows some convesation to detent the mapping. So custom repository must ends with Custom and name of implementation class should end with Impl (you can override this settings, but its default which will do in most of the cases)